# Active Navbar State in React is Resetting

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, navbar

I am trying to make the actively selected navbar element change the background color via react state. However it does not fully work. When I click on an element in my navbar, it briefly gets styled correctly, but after a moment is reverted and my homepage element in the navbar becomes styled once more.

I have my (simplified) navbar code below:

```
function Navbar(props) {
  const [clickedNavbarItem, setClickedNavbarItem] = React.useState("/");

  return (
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a
          onClick={() => setClickedNavbarItem("/")}
          className={clickedNavbarItem === "/" && "active"}
          href="/"
          >Solve
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a
          onClick={() => setClickedNavbarItem("/about")}
          className={clickedNavbarItem === "/about" && "active"}
          href="/about"
        >About
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

To my understanding: When the user clicks a given anchor tag, it should run the onClick handler, which will re-assign the state. The navbar should then re-render, and the classname for the appropriately clicked item should have the "active" class, which should change the styling.

Additionally, the href should redirect the page as such (this is my React router code):

```
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Solve />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/explain" element={<Explain />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

I believe there is some interaction where the Navbar is getting reset perhaps when the href is activated, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help is appreciated.